# Intuition behind denoting the power set of $\Omega$ as $\{0,1\}^\Omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand a textbook example, specifically I want to understand why the notation is the way it is.  I'm new to this.

A die is thrown once.  We can take the sample space
$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

We can take a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F= \{0,1\}^\Omega$ (all possible subsets).

I understand why we want to reason about $\mathcal F$, and I understand why its cardinality is 2^6.  Since we're raising a 2-element set to a 6-element set, that kind of makes sense with this notation.

But from reading, I get that $X^Y=\{f\colon Y\to X\mid f\ \text{is a function}\}$

But this gives me a set of functions, right?   While the power set notation gives me something I think of as a set of sets.

Which piece am I oversimplifying or missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every subset $A$ of $\Omega$ can be identified with the function $1_A:\Omega\to\{0,1\}$ defined by $1_A(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\in A$ and $1_A(\omega)=0$ if $\omega\notin A$. So there are as many such functions as there are subsets and we might identify them for most purposes.