# Find a one-to-one function from a set S to the set of functions from S to {0,1}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find a one-to-one function from a set S to the set of functions from S to {0,1}.

This is a set theory question. S can be an any set. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem). Take into account that you can think of a function $S\to\{0,1\}$ as the subset of $S$ where that function is $1$.

Comment: Cantor's Theorem as in plop's comment. Also you might look at this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492544

Answer (score 1):

A function from $S$ to $\{0, 1\}$ is the same as a subset of $S$ (the elements of the subset being the elements of $S$ mapped to $1$).

For example, for $s \in S$, you can take $\{s\}$ to be the image. In this case, you define :
$$\Phi : \begin{aligned} S &\longrightarrow \mathcal{F} (S, \{0, 1\}) \\ s &\longmapsto \chi_s \end{aligned}$$
where $\chi_s : S \to \{0, 1\}$ maps $x$ to $1$ if $x=s$ and $0$ otherwise.

The map $\Phi$ is injective (one-to-one) because if $\Phi(x) = \Phi(y)$ then by definition $\chi_x = \chi_y$, which means that $\chi_y(x) = 1$ so $y = x$.

Side note : you can never find a surjective (onto) function from $S$ to $\mathcal F(S, \{0, 1\})$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the idea but I really didn't know how to explain it was one-to-one. This makes a lot of sense, and yes, I am also proving that we can never find an onto function from S to F.